# Jquery click function adds to DOM, how to bind new insertions?

Tags: jquery, dom, onclick

I have a function that copies values from a table1 to a table2. The function checks the second table to make sure there are enough rows before it performs the copy, and if there are not enough rows it creates them with `addRows(n)`.

```
$('#copyTableValues').on('click', function() {
    // count available rows and add more if needed
    if(table2Rows < rowsNeeded)
    {
        addRows(rowsNeeded - table2Rows);
    }

    // copy values from table1 to table2
    // ....

});
```

However the function does not recognize the rows that were most recently inserted with addRows. If I click the copy function again, it recognizes them.

My understanding is that this is because jquery checks for changes to the DOM only during the `.on('click')` part of this function. Is there a way to ask it to check again in the cases where I make additions to the DOM after the click?

Comment: Post your code which counts the number of existing rows in table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to move up a little in your hierarchy though.

Try:

```
$('body').on('click', '#copyTableValues', function() {

});
```

This will watch `'body'` for any additions of `'#copyTableValues'`, and apply the event to them as well. The  way you have only addresses pieces that are already loaded into the DOM when the script hits those lines.

Comment: While your code is correct, your explanation is a bit off. `$.on()` in this case binds to `<body>` which isn't created dynamically, and watches for events that _bubble up_ from children of `<body>`. The ID filter is matched against the relevant bubbled events.

Comment: @JamWaffles I was being vague, and a lot of time people who don't grasp this simple level concept would have a much harder time grasping bubbling.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I solved it using a trigger. I added `$('#table2').trigger('additionComplete')` to the end of `addRows()`. I then prefaced the copy function with `$('#table2').on('additionComplete', function() {`